# How can I correct my code to return all matching cities separate div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash, loops

I have the following piece of JS code within a function that responds to the user pressing enter (not displayed). The part of the code I am concerned with is shown:

```
   $.each(cityhash,function(key,value){
        if(value['city']== user_input) {
            $('#city').append(value['city']);
            $('#state').append(value['state']);
        }
```

I have the following hash:

```
cityhash =  [{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","state":"Missouri"},{"address":"0615 Mervin Rapid","city":"Tessmouth","state":"South Carolina"},{"address":"779 Elody Lock","city":"Littelside","state":"New Mexico"}]
```

As you can see, the city of **Littelside appears twice in the hash**. My problem is if there are two city matches, the cities are placed directly beside one another. For example LittelsideLittelside. I would like each matching Littelside, to appear in its own div. How do I do this?

**How can I correct my code to return all matching cities in their own separate div**?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you display the rest of the code that displays the addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the city text in an element with `id="city"`, I would make an element with `id="cities"` and then append the city elements inside of that.

```
$('#cities').append('<div class="city">' + value['city'] + ', ' + 
    value['state'] + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('#city').append($("<div>").html(value['city']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prev_city;

$.each(cityhash,function(key,value){
    if(value['city']== user_input) {
        $('#city').append(value['city']);
        $('#state').append(value['state']);

        if(value['city'] == prev_city){
            // Append to new div logic
        } else {
            prev_city = value['city'];
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure how you are printing the cities out right now but basically you need to track the previous city to know if you need to append another div.

Comment: What tell you that they are ordered?

Comment: True that, didn't think of that. Could get messy.